# Есть ли в unity коллайдер - бублик?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Странно звучит но мне бы такой коллайдер пригодился бы, вот рисунок мало ли вдруг есть а я не знаю[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: меш-коллайдер не подходит?

Comment: Нет, торуса отдельным коллайдером в Unity нет.

Answer (score 0):

Как по мне, было бы очень удобно создать пустой объект, или взять объект на котором вы собирались разместить такой коллайдер. На него повесить 4 бокс коллайдера и написать скрипт, в котором будут публичные переменные ширина всего коллайдера, длина всего коллайдера, длина и ширина пустоты. Пусть при старте этот скрипт изменяет соответствующим образом размеры этих коллайдеров в зависимости от заданных значений.